# RF switch acting like a splitter

Tags: rf, switches

I'm trying to use a pair of RF switches (SKY13421-486LF) to switch two channels between the circuit output and a matching resistor: I have two inputs and want to pass one to the output and dump the other. I'm using a 3.3V supply, and this problem appears on all the devices I've checked. The signals in question would be in the order of 100-150MHz.

[image: Switches schematic]

However, instead of acting as a switch both devices act more like a splitter, passing the input to both outputs equally, regardless of the control voltage. That is, a signal input to either U6 or U7 appears on both R7 and C10.

I've tried changing the matching resistor value and placing DC blocking capacitors on the outputs without success. Searching around hasn't led to anything, but that might be because I have no idea what search terms to use.

Has anyone seen anything like this before, or have any suggestions on how to stop them acting like splitters?

EDIT:

@Bimpelrekkie: I've tried placing capacitors by cutting and strapping on the outputs with no success. The input of U7 is DC blocked at the origin of the input signal.

@Andy aka: Powering on, yes. It does occur to me that powering off is done by just cutting the power, so that C98 and C99 might hold the voltage at the VCTL pin higher than VDD for however long it takes to discharge. The datasheet doesn't seem to specify the tolerance of the device for this, so I'll email Skyworks and ask.

EDIT again:

Contrary to what I wrote above, placing capacitors on the output pins of both switches does work. It may have been a layout issue or an accidental short while cutting and strapping. Note that putting caps on one set of outputs is not enough.

Comment: I don't see R7.

Comment: @Andyaka It is the 75 Ohm resistor right of B2 (bottom balun)

Comment: Have you observed the rigorous regime for activating/powering the chip, setting the control voltage and applying input signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that I notice is that in the Evaluation board diagram all inputs and outputs are AC coupled:

[image]

Your schematic has AC coupling at only one of the RF switches' inputs but **not** at the inputs of the other RF switch and nowhere on the outputs.

It isn't clear to me **if** this will disturb the switching behavior of the RF switches but there is a large chance that it will. What you could do is measure the DC voltages at the outputs of the switches with and without the baluns present and with and without one of the switches present.

In your design the outputs of the two RF switches are in parallel. **If** the design relies on a certain DC voltage (which is set by the chip itself) to be present at the outputs but you overrule that voltage then the RF switches might not work as expected.

So: add AC coupling directly at the outputs of the RF switches and see if that helps.

Comment: +1. I'd imagine that the RF inputs/outputs are DC-coupled to their respective circuit elements, and applying an external DC voltage will likely pull the transistors out of the correct bias point.